# How to Model Multiple Relationships in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to finish building a Rails "Home Inventory" app as an example to help me learn rails. Following gives a general overview of what I am trying to achieve:

The main purpose of this application is to show a page with detailed information.

So,    http://localhost:3000/living-room-couch would display the information regarding the couch.

Each Item, can belong one( or has one?) of three categories:

1. Book
2. Furniture
3. Electronics.

**Book** has the following properties:
 - isbn,
 - pages,
 - address,
 - category

**Furniture** has following properties:
 - color,
 - price,
 - address,
 - category

**Electronics** has following properties:
 - name,
 - voltage,
 - address,
 - category.

--

Now on my **View** side, I have made 3 templates in rails, that contain elements suited to display an item belonging to one of the 3 categories. Template for **Book** shows isbn, and template for **Electronics** shows the voltage.

**How do I model this in ActiveRecord?** I will put it in English, maybe someone can help translate into Rails:

An Item, belongs_to or has_one *category*. Category can be one of the three: *Book*, *Furniture*, or *Electronic*.

I don't know how to do this. I know that each category like **Book** will be a model of its own, due to having different characteristics.

Do I need to have **Category** has a model too, because it would only consist of **Book**, or **Furniture** or **Electronics**. If I was to take the route of making Category a model of its own, how would I make it relate to a model such as **Book**.

---

**--or**

Would I just go this route (or join model perhaps):

```
class BookModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
End
```

And then, select to which category belongs, based on the Model name.

I hope I put the question right, I am just so confused regarding this.

Thank You for your time.

Comment: From my experiences I have realized that Rails makes the barrier to entry smaller, but just adds more barriers to  jump over. No such thing as free lunch I suppose.

I think the polymorphic approach might be a right one. So off I go to read that chapter again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `category` model. You can just create the `book`, `furniture` and `electronic` models and one `controller` for each one.

**Edit**

No, there's no advantage. I just said to create different models/controllers because what you're modeling, in my opinion, are different things. But if you think they'll have a lot in common, I'd suggest for you to use single table inheritance. This way you'd have a single table for every item and can have only one controller, but each item would have one model.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using multiple controllers, versus just relating the models using some form of relationships and just using one controller.

I say that because the controller will have one purpose: to determine which category the item is and then    render the appropriate    template.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have an Item have the following relationships:

```
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :furniture
belongs_to :electronic
```

You can then only actually set on of these, and can do a test of

```
if item.book
#do things
end
```

for each item, if you care about whether it's a book, etc.  You can even use validations to make sure it only ever belongs to one thing at a time.

Comment: I actually got that idea right as I was typing this question into S.O.
So what you are saying is that I should have a model for every category? So far, I would have Item Model. And I would add additional models for Categories other than Books, Furniture, and Electronics correct?

Comment: Sure, though I'm not exactly sure why you would need an Item model (are you just trying to show that Books, Furniture and Electronics are all Items? Like a form of super class?), but in general, that's how I handle a Model that might belong to one or more other models.

Comment: Just from your description, I personally wouldn't have an item at all, and just worry about Book/Furniture/Electronics.  If you ever need to display everything in the database, then display @books, @furniture, etc. in a row? 

For example, I might have a Cat model and a Mouse model...but I wouldn't gain much from ALSO having an Animal model that both belong to unless I planned on doing something with the inheritance. If I ever want to show all animals, then I just show all cats, and all mice, you know?

Comment: Thank you for your response Jenny.

Apeacox below responded with a need for Polymorphic relation which I think makes sense. I mean, from what I understand, since an ITEM, has one CATEGORY. And the model CATEGORY consists of BOOK, or FURNITURE models(with appropriate database fields), it would make sense to have ITEM be a polymorphic, so that it can apply to BOOK, or FURNITURE. I mean in plain English, what I am trying to do is, find out how to make CATEGORY model consist of BOOK, and FURNITURE model, so that I can attach an ITEM to a category, so that in the view, I can render the rite templat

Answer (score 0):

the Item model could be declared as polymorphic (se here: http://guides.rails.info/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

so you'll declare Item:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, :polymorphic => true
end
```

then the 3 models that act as category (I'll show one, the others are same):

```
 class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :item, :as => :category
 end

 # and so on...
```

this way you can associate an Item to one of the 3 models (Book, Furniture and Electronics).
each instance of these models will have an 'items' atribute, like this:

```
@book.items # returns all the items associated to a @book object
```

You can also use has_many association using a polymorphic model.

For the views, you can use Nested Form Objects (see here: http://guides.rails.info/form_helpers.html). basically, in each form, you should nest a form to create an Item object. to follow the Book example, you'll have something like this:

```
 <%= form_for :book, @book do |form| %>
   <%= form.text_field :isbn %>
   <!-- other fields -->
   <%= fields_for @book.item do |item_form| %>
      <%= item_form.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

hope this helped you ;)

Comment: Apeacox, Thank you for your response.

I watched a Ryan Bates video the other day, and I somewhat understood Polymorphic relations. His example of a comment being applicable to different models made sense. I had a feeling I might need to apply the polymorphic relation here as well.

Please verify if this the best approach: BOOK,FURNITURE all belong to model CATEGORY, which belongs to ITEM, or ITEM has one category(BOOK,or FURNITURE). Do I need the model category at all? If i do I would assume that I would make the ITEM model a polymorphic one, that can belong to any one of 3 CATEGORIES. Right?

Comment: yes, if you make Item polymorphic, it can belong to one of the 3 categories. you'll refer to them as 'category' (see the example in my answer). so an @item can do @item.category_id and @item.category_type to know the exact object (class and id of the model), then you can refer to @item.category.isbn if the category is a Book or @item.category.price if it's a Furniture